# Copy files with Space in the name

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have list of files which I need to copy from one location to another

Input File:
c:/Unknown/Absolute.txt
c:/Unknown/Absolute With Space.txt

If I try a script to read the input file and do a cp to a destination directory it fails ,The file Absolute.txt gets copied like I wanted however the  Absolute With Space.txt doesn't . How would I achieve copying the file names with space ??

Answer (score 4):

Space is used as separation character, if you don't want that, use `"quotes"` or escape the spaces with `\_` (where `_` is a space). So this should both work:

```
cp "c:/Unknown/Absolute.txt" "c:/Unknown/Absolute With Space.txt"
cp c:/Unknown/Absolute.txt c:/Unknown/Absolute\ With\ Space.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

In general, if you are dealing with variables instead of direct locations use this code

```
source="c:/Unknown/Absolute.txt"
destination="c:/Unknown/Absolute With Space.txt"

if(' ' not in destination):
    !copy $source $destination
else:
    !copy $source "$destination"
```

This works in Windows OS